# Can you extract text from pdf using slate

Tags: python, pdf, scrapy

I am working on a scrapy spider, trying to extract text multiple pdfs in a directory, using slate (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slate) So far I have:

```
class Ove_Spider(BaseSpider):

    name = "ove"


    allowed_domains = ['myurl.com']
    start_urls = ['myurl/hgh/']


    def parse(self, response):
        for a in response.xpath('//a[@href]/@href'):
            link = a.extract()
            if link.endswith('.pdf'):
                link = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, link)
                yield Request(link, callback=self.save_pdf)

    def save_pdf(self, response):
        path = response.url.split('/')[-1]
        # get_pdf_content(base_url+path)
        with open(base_url+path, 'rb') as f:
            doc = slate.PDF(f)
            print(doc[0])
```

I'm getting:

```
File ....spiders\ove_spider.py", line 38, in save_pdf
with open(base_url+path, 'rb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:
```

I've checked the path to the pdf, and it is correct (base_url+path gives absolute path to remote server), so for some reason this is not opening the remote file for reading. How can I get this working?

Comment: The downloaded PDF content is available through `response.body`. I don't see that you are saving these bytes to a file before ingesting the content into slate. You can probably also not save the data to file and use `BytesIO` to fake the file for slate.

Comment: Thank you, you've clarified my thoughts partially on what I need to do. I want to to save the file to an in "in memory" pdf and then access that. I don't want to save the file .

Comment: @user61629: or you could save it to a Python `tempfile`

Comment: I just looked up python tempfiles (https://pymotw.com/2/tempfile/) , never having heard of it before. Is there an advantage to this over  keeping info in memory?

Comment: user61629 a) Can have lots of tempfiles in use simultaneously b) You can have them persist, very useful if your program crashes or for debugging. Then delete when finished. c) If they're large files, avoid blowing out the cache or main memory. Can you step back and explain why you don't want to use a file? What size data are we dealing with?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. No I didn't mean I didn't want to use this. I was simply not aware of this as a language feature. I'll keep in mind for the future.